How to change cookie expiration with Sustainsys.Saml mvc?
I am using Sustainsys mvc successfully but found that after 8-10 hours the FedAuth cookie for Sustainsys expires. Is there a way to easily extend the expiration date to something like 14 days? Alternatively, will logging off the IDP before 8 hours solve the problem?
I tried setting the authentication timeout out to 2 minutes but that didn't initiate a call to re-login. Also tried changing attributes for the cookieHandler FedAuth setting to make the cookie expiration date longer but it was still expiring after 8-10 hours:
My next step is to look in the Sustainsys.saml2 code to see if I can change cookie expiration there. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way.
This problem hasn't been reported yet for the .NET Core apps we have using Sustainsys, only the MVC 4.8 apps.
Edit: going to try using SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived and setting a sliding expiration
Edit 2: I got code working that renewed the cookie after half its expiration time was reached but then I read you shouldn't do this with auth cookies.
I also figured out the problem was due to a setTimeout called every 30 minutes, which seemed to be a problem when the user's screen had been inactive for 10 hours, during which time the cookie expired. When setTimeout wasn't called, this problem wasn't seen on logging in the next day. I'm handling this by changing the setTimeout to stop running with inactivity, then wake back up when there's some activity.
Edit: this didn't work. Still lost auth after 10 hours
